# How to show only one week with cal/ncal command?

Tags: bash, calendar

I cant figure out how to show only one week. 
I tried ncal -w 1 for example, but it shows me 1st year instead of 1st week, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't list a week with ncal without some extra processing:

```
$ week=20 ncal -hbwm \
  $(date -d "01-jan now $((week-1)) weeks" +%m\ %Y) | \
  grep -e '^[[:blank:]]w|' -e "^[[:blank:]]*$week|"
```

- `-h` Turns off highlighting of today.
- `-b` Use oldstyle format for ncal output.
- `-w` Print the number of the week.
- `-m` Display the specified month.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what the command was supposed to do. Old age etc :)  Just realised the first line was the days of the week in French...

Comment: `-e '^[[:blank:]]w|.*'` matches days of the week and the second one the dates.